# Linq - Retrieve value from a linked linked table

Tags: linq

I have the following model and relationship:

```
Table: Granddad
GranddadID
GranddadName

Table: Father
FatherID
GranddadID
FatherName

Table: Son
SonID
FatherID
SonName
```

in the Granddad controller:

```
public ActionResult Edit(int tmpgranddadid)
{
   var q = (from g in _e.Grandad
           where g.GrandadID == tmpgranddadid
           select g).FirstOrDefault();

   string son_name = q.Father.Son.SonName.ToString(); // <- is wrong, how to do this?

   return View(q);
}
```

How do you retrieve the value from a linked linked table?

Thank you

Comment: You should follow the naming guidelines. Just a sidenote.

Comment: @Filip: Care to elucidate, I think there are many naming guidelines that could apply here.

Comment: A father can have more than one son. Which one do you want?

Comment: Regarding naming. I think Son.SonName is very confusing (the name of the son's son maybe?).  What's wrong with Son.Name?

Comment: You should have a Person table with a Father relation to the same table imho. This is silly, a GrandFather without any Fathers is per definition only a Son.

Comment: @Wouter: Yep, classic scenario for HIERARCHYID field if this is SQL Server 2008.

Comment: sorry all about the naming. i was trying to ask a question about how to access a value from a distant relationship. i don't know what other example to use :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your data source looks something like this:

```
public class SomeDataSource
{
    public List<Granddad> Granddad;
    public List<Father> Father;
    public List<Son> Son;
}
```

And assuming you're actually after the *first grandson for a granddad* then:

```
var firstGrandson = (from son in _e.Son
               join father in _e.Father on son.FatherID equals father.FatherID
               join granddad in _e.Granddad on father.GranddadID equals granddad.GranddadID
               where granddad.GranddadID == tmpgranddadid
               select son).FirstOrDefault();

if (firstGrandson == null)
    throw new Exception("This granddad has no grandsons.");

string son_name = firstGrandson.SonName;
```

Is this what you needed?

Comment: Dear Codesleuth. Thanks for that :) Sorry abit slow to try your example I am really new. I tired your code but when I got to "join father in _e.Father on son.FatherID" I can't get the FatherID to show up. In my model view FatherID is kind in "Navigation Properties"

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you want any of the possibly many sons?

```
q.Fathers.First().Sons.First().SonName.ToString();
```

Be careful though because First() can throw an exception if a father has no sons. This will handle that case:

```
string sonName = null;
Father father = q.Fathers.FirstOrDefault();
if (father != null) {
    Son son = father.Sons.FirstOrDefault();
    if (son != null) {
        sonName = son.SonName.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: LOL, thanks Mark :)


I reduced it and tried that. However I got an error for: q.Fathers.First().FatherName.ToString().

The error is: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.


Please help :)


Also apart from using First() is there another method I can use to specify [n] son/element? I tried to used ElementAt(0) and I don’t know how to use AsQueryable and it all failed :(

Thank you

Comment: I've updated my answer to show you how to handle the case where a father has no sons.

Comment: You might want to check if a reference is loaded with `IsLoaded()` and `Load()` if needed.

Comment: Thanks mark :) Tried it and got: "Sequence contains no elements." Checked the father table and there are data... Anyideas?

Answer (score 0):

Check out joins:

http://www.hookedonlinq.com/JoinOperator.ashx